# Intercom js api - Messanger isOpen status

Tags: intercom

Looking at the [docs](https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/docs/intercom-javascript), I am able to open and close Intercom Messenger by doing:

`window.Intercom('show')`
and
`window.Intercom('hide')`

I can't find if there is a possibility to get the status of the Messenger (is it open or closed (eg. `isOpen`). Is there a way to obtain this status?

I know I can implement `onShow` and `onHide` events and possibly create a local var to track the status, but it would be much better if the API exposed the field to read this status.